# How to write rows to a .csv file using .iloc in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I am searching a .csv file for some numbers using a regular expression. Then when the numbers match, the index of those rows is written to a .csv using .iloc but getting an error.

```
for each in temp:

      if doLuhn(str(each)) is True:
          #print ("In the loop")
          creditcards.append(each)
          Validcardsfound = Validcardsfound + 1
          regex_match_index_list.append(i)
```

then

```
for each in regex_match_index_list:
df.iloc[each].to_csv('test.csv')
```

Note : I have create an empty dataframe df.

But I am getting the following error

> IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in the number of columns after .iloc instead of "each". Lets say you have 18 columns try the following:
    df.iloc[:,17].to_csv('test.csv')

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the list that you created based on some requirement (regex_match_index_list) to a file test.csv: maybe you can try converting it to a data frame of one column and write it.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(regex_match_index_list, columns=['column_name_you_want']).to_csv('test.csv')
```

Comment: I dont want to append a single column. I want to append the entire row with all columns.